# How to move all files from multiple directories to their parent directories using bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

I have the following file structure:

- /home/data/C01/**dir_wwe_346**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- /home/data/C02/**dir_wwe_644**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- /home/data/C03/**dir_wwe_324**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh

I want them to be this way:

- home/data/C01/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- home/data/C02/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- home/data/C03/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh

It's basically moving multiple files one directory up, I have tried this script without success:

`#!/bin/bash
for i in */
do
        cd i/*/
        mv * ../
done`

---

After posting this (but before reading grawity response below), I realised I did not use the proper variable expansion, and run this:

`#!/bin/bash
for i in */
do
        cd ${i}*wwe*
        mv * ../
done`

The script is moving all the subdirectories to the data folder, so I am ending up with this:

- /**home**/C01/**dir_wwe_346**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- /**home**/C02/**dir_wwe_644**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh
- /**home**/C03/**dir_wwe_324**/file1.txt pic.jpg random.sh

  What am I doing wrong?

---

PS. I edited the post so that it reveals the process I went through, and so that responses make more sense for new comers that might benefit from these responses. Thanks grawity, I learned something new. I have just started learning bash a week ago and I feel I am progressing.

Comment: Does each top-level directory have _exactly one_ subdirectory?

Comment: Yeah, only one each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Variables are only recognized and expanded with the `$` prefix. If the loop defines a variable 'i', you need to use **`$i`** whenever you want its value:

   ```
   for i in */; do
       cd $i/*/
   ```
2. The "current directory" is process-wide and does not automatically reset every loop iteration. You need either to manually return to the parent directory afterwards:

   ```
   cd $i/*/; mv * ../; cd ../../
   ```

   or use a "subshell" to scope the directory change:

   ```
   (cd $i/*/; mv * ../)
   ```
3. You're not doing any error checking. If the `cd` ever fails, the subsequent `mv` can do unpleasant things. Either join commands using `&&` or do the opposite check and use `|| exit` (or `|| break`), whichever looks best:

   ```
   for i in */; do
       cd $i/*/ && {
           mv * ../;
           cd ../../
       }
   done

   for i in */; do
       cd $i/*/ || exit
       mv * ../
       cd ../../
   done

   for i in */; do
       (cd $i/*/ && mv * ../)
   done
   ```
4. Improvement: You could move the subdirectory wildcard to `mv`, allowing it to work even in case there are multiple subdirectories:

   ```
   cd $i/ || exit
   mv */* .
   cd ../
   ```
5. Improvement: You could do this without needing `cd` at all:

   ```
   mv $i/*/* $i/
   ```